# How can i make this code more automated when changing the content of the buttons?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I made this code to start making a TicTacToe game, i'm pretty sure there's a way of making one function that changes the content of the button that has been last pressed or something similar.

How can i make it into a more shorter version?

I think i can use .self and make one fucntion but i don't know how.

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

l1b1 = tk.StringVar()
l1b1.set("0")
l1b2 = tk.StringVar()
l1b2.set("0")
l1b3 = tk.StringVar()
l1b3.set("0")

l2b1 = tk.StringVar()
l2b1.set("0")
l2b2 = tk.StringVar()
l2b2.set("0")
l2b3 = tk.StringVar()
l2b3.set("0")

l3b1 = tk.StringVar()
l3b1.set("0")
l3b2 = tk.StringVar()
l3b2.set("0")
l3b3 = tk.StringVar()
l3b3.set("0")


def l1b1co():
l1b1.set("x")


def l1b2co():
    l1b2.set("x")


def l1b3co():
    l1b3.set("x")


def l2b1co():
    l2b1.set("x")


def l2b2co():
l2b2.set("x")


def l2b3co():
    l2b3.set("x")


def l3b1co():
    l3b1.set("x")


def l3b2co():
    l3b2.set("x")


def l3b3co():
    l3b3.set("x")


tk.Button(main, textvariable=l1b1, command=l1b1co).grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l1b2, command=l1b2co).grid(column=1, row=0)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l1b3, command=l1b3co).grid(column=2, row=0)

tk.Button(main, textvariable=l2b1, command=l2b1co).grid(column=0, row=1)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l2b2, command=l2b2co).grid(column=1, row=1)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l2b3, command=l2b3co).grid(column=2, row=1)

tk.Button(main, textvariable=l3b1, command=l3b1co).grid(column=0, row=2)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l3b2, command=l3b2co).grid(column=1, row=2)
tk.Button(main, textvariable=l3b3, command=l3b3co).grid(column=2, row=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a dictionary or list of lists, and create everything in a loop.

Since you're creating three rows with three columns, you can use a loop to iterate over the rows, and in each iteration you can loop over the columns. You can use the row and column number to reference each variable or button.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

buttons = {}
button_vars = {}

def setVar(row, column, value):
    button_vars[row, column].set(value)

for row in range(3):
    for column in range(3):
        var = tk.StringVar(value="0")
        button = tk.Button(main, textvariable=var,
                           command=lambda row=row, column=column: setVar(row, column, "x"))
        button.grid(row=row, column=column)

        button_vars[row, column] = var
        buttons[row, column] = button

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, being curious `command=lambda` what does `lamba` does?

Comment: @G_man: I can't answer that in the comments. It's well documented in many places, and there are hundreds of questions about it on this site. The short answer is that it's more-or-less a function without a name.